# How do I make a dictionary from a Python counter with the right keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to both Python and programming so please forgive a potentially stupid question.

I am using the Counter method from the collections module on a list and I am using dict() on this to make a dictionary from the results:

```
state_count = ['Alabama','Alabama','Alabama','Alaska','Alaska']
print dict(Counter(state_count))
```

The data comes out looking like this:

```
{'Alabama': '3', 'Alaska': '2'} etc.
```

What I want is to create a dictionary where the state name is a key and it would look like this:

```
{'state':'Alabama','other_value':'3'}
{'state':'Alaska','other_value':'2'}
```

The solution doesn't have to include using the Counter method, I just want to take a list that has each state name multiple times and get a count of how many times each state name is mentioned using the above dictionary format.

Comment: your output is not clear,

Comment: Why this doesn't work for you:`{'Alabama': '3', 'Alaska': '2'}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the dictionary items and do printing the keys,values as values of string keys `state` and `other_value`.

```
from collections import Counter
state_count = ['Alabama','Alabama','Alabama','Alaska','Alaska']
m = Counter(state_count)
for i, j in m.items():
    print {'state':i, 'other_value':j}
```

Output:

```
{'state': 'Alabama', 'other_value': 3}
{'state': 'Alaska', 'other_value': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the data in a list of dicts format, you can easily create such a list:

```
from collections import Counter
state_count = ['Alabama','Alabama','Alabama','Alaska','Alaska']
dict_list = [{"state":k,"other_value":v} for k,v in Counter(state_count).items()]

print dict_list[0] #{'state': 'Alabama','other_value': 3}
print dict_list[0]["state"] #'Alabama'
```

This leaves you with the data in a usable form and not just printed output.